# Show markers behind polygons

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I have created circle (type polygon, with computed coordinates by [this formula](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/2167#issuecomment-169265375) - still not sure if this is best way to render circle...)

and some markers, representing cities.
I prefer markers, because they are html elements and I can style them.

Circle serves as a radius for selecting cities.

My question is, how can I position these markers **behind** circle? Circle is part of canvas, and markers are separated divs, so there won't help any z-index.

Or should I create those markers somehow as points in canvas?

Looking exactly for [this behaviour](https://kiwi.com/), only in mapboxgl.

Comment: Did you consider using the [`circle` layer type](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/#layers-circle)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/kmandov/vzc0o86g/

You can use [turf-circle](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/tree/master/packages/turf-circle) to create a circle using a specified radius and units. Turf-circle generates a `geojson` object that can be added to its own layer.

```
var center = {
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "marker-color": "#0f0"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [-77.1117, 38.8739]
  }
};

var lasso = turf.circle(center, 5, 20, 'kilometers');
```

Then you add it to its own layer. I've called it `lasso`:

```
  map.addSource('lasso', {
    'type': 'geojson',
    'data': lasso
  });

  map.addLayer({
    'id': 'lasso',
    'type': 'fill',
    'source': 'lasso',
    'paint': {
      'fill-color': '#f1f075',
      'fill-opacity': 0.8
    }
  });
```

Then you add the layer containing the stations by specifying the layer above([example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-layer-in-stack/)). This will make sure that the `lasso layer` is above the `stations layer`:

```
  map.addLayer({
    'id': 'stations',
    'type': 'circle',
    'source': 'stations',
    'paint': {
      'circle-color': '#feb24c',
      'circle-opacity': 1,
      'circle-radius': 5
    }
  }, 'lasso'); // lasso is the layer above
```